# Xen configure host-only adapter

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, xen

Xen hypervisor has 2 modes for network configuration as I've seen in Virtual Manager. 1 NAT 2 Routed. Both ask for IP Subnet. However i want to configure a network where i could assign any IP instead of being assigned by DHCP of Xen.

I've use oracle Virtual Box there is an option to use Host-only adapter. I want to use Xen in that way.

In other words i want to share physical network interface to guest machine(VM)

I'm using Xen Hypervisor 3.x on CentOS 6.2 x86_64

I did the following to solve the issue this worked for me.

```
Disabling Xen's network scripts
If using Xen it is recommended to disable its network munging by editing /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp and changing the line
(network-script network-bridge)

To be

(network-script /bin/true)

Disabling NetworkManager

As of the time of writing (Fedora 12), NetworkManager still does not support bridging, so it is necessary to use "classic" network initscripts for the bridge, and to explicitly mark them as independent from NetworkManager (the "NM_CONTROLLED=no" lines in the scripts below).

If desired, you can also completely disable the NetworkManager:

# chkconfig NetworkManager off
# chkconfig network on
# service NetworkManager stop
# service network start

Creating network initscripts

In the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts directory it is neccessary to create 2 config files. The first (ifcfg-eth0) defines your physical network interface, and says that it will be part of a bridge:

# cat > ifcfg-eth0 <<EOF
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:16:76:D6:C9:45
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
EOF

Obviously change the HWADDR to match your actual NIC's address. You may also wish to configure the device's MTU here using e.g. MTU=9000.

The second config file (ifcfg-br0) defines the bridge device:

# cat > ifcfg-br0 <<EOF
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
EOF

WARNING: The line TYPE=Bridge is case-sensitive - it must have uppercase 'B' and lower case 'ridge'

After changing this restart networking (or simply reboot)

# service network restart
```

[Visit for more details](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Fedora.2FRHEL_Bridging)

Comment: Are you using Citrix' XenServer?

Answer (score 1):

For Xen, this is just a special case of bridged networking.

You create a dummy bridge on your CentOS Dom0, then connect your VM to that bridge.

From the CentOS Documention (http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Virtualized_network_devices-Laptop_network_configuration.html)

create a dummy0 network interface and assign it a static IP address.

In our example I selected 10.1.1.1 to avoid routing problems in our environment. To enable dummy device support add the following lines to /etc/modprobe.conf

```
alias dummy0 dummy
options dummy numdummies=1
```

To configure networking for dummy0 edit/create /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-dummy0:

```
DEVICE=dummy0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.1.1.1
ARP=yes
```

You can then just connect your VM to the dummy0 bridge device

Additional Reference
http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/HostConfiguration/Networking